# Using Shared Memory with PLCSIM respectively with non-shared-memory-prepared applications

Tags: c++, shared-memory, plc

I want to use shared memory between two applications. In this case between a c++ main-application and PLCSIM, a virtual programmable logic controller. Anyway I did not know if PLCSIM is prepared for shared memory usage. Is it possible to force PLCSIM to make it memory storage available for other processes like shown in the MSDN-example related to a main-main-interprocess-communication example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Unlikely.  You'll have to contact Siemens if you want to be sure.

Comment: Thanks Hans - I called one of the Siemens guys and they second your statement. It won't work.

Comment: What is your use case? PLCSIM offers the S7ProSim COM interface that will allow you to interact with PLCSIM from another process. Since you called support, I guess you know about this API. If you provide more details, I might know a way to solve your problem. S7ProSim documentation is available at https://cache.automation.siemens.com/dnl/DE/DE2NTA2OQAA_1139855_HB/S7WSPSCB.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure what your end goal is but could you look at using NettoPLCSim.  It makes use of a "COM-Interface of PLCSim to read/write the data out of it".  You could use source code to make    an application to store data to where you require to share with your C++ code
http://nettoplcsim.sourceforge.net/